# Webpack and jQuery with Symfony 4.3

Tags: jquery, symfony, webpack

I use Symfony 4.3 and I have this issue :"Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined" when I try to accessing jQuery from outside of webpack.config.js.

My webpack.config.js :

```
 Encore
    // ...
    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
    //...
    .autoProvidejQuery()
;
```

My app.js in assets/js/app.js

```
var $ = require('jquery');
global.$ = global.jQuery = $;
require('bootstrap');
require('../css/app.scss');
require('../css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

The calendar in my twig file :

```
{% block javascripts %}
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#booking_startDate, #booking_endDate').datepicker({
                format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
                datesDisabled: [
                    {% for day in ad.notAvailableDays %}
                        "{{ day.format('d/m/Y') }}",
                    {% endfor %}
                ],
                startDate: new Date()
            });

            $('#booking_startDate, #booking_endDate').on('change',calculateAmount);
        });
```

"npm run dev" is working fine but I have no css, js or jQuery when I refresh this page only (other parts of my website is working fine with CSS, JS..).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `import` instead:

```
import $ from "jquery";
global.$ = global.jQuery = $;
```

As `.autoProvidejQuery()` is meant to make jQuery global (available from `window`), it should then works as you need.

As a side note, don't use `import` for CSS. It will fail in prod.

Comment: I tried as below into the assets/app.js file :                                                               
`import $ from "jquery";                                                           
global.$ = global.jQuery = $;

require('bootstrap');

require('../css/app.scss');
require('../css/bootstrap.min.css');`                                                                           but doesn't seems to work. I followed the official doc for symfony 4.3 [link](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/simple-example.html)

Comment: jQuery should works as provided in my answer. If it doesn't, it mean that the script requiring javascript might be executed before jQuery is initialized (scripts order matter). Did you try, after this change, to call `$` in the dev console?

Comment: I keep the "require('jquery') for now, it's working fine in dev mode and I will try in a few days when I will upload my site and switch in prod mode. Thanks a lot for your advice

Comment: Effectively I had to replace in prod mod `var $ = require('jquery');` with `import $ "from jquery";` Thanks a lot for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for the css :

1. Create a css file in the assets/css to import the css for the datepicker :
   assets/css/book.css

```
    @import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css');
```

2. Create book.js to call book.css : 
   assets/js/book.js

```
require ('../css/book.css');
```

3. Call this on my template as below : 
   templates/book.html.twig

```
    {% block stylesheets %}
        {{ parent() }} 
        {{ encore_entry_link_tags('book') }}
    {% endblock %}
```

It works! I will try to fix for the javascript in this way